# linux shows the wrong distro name

Tags: boot, gnome, budgie

i installed ubuntu  budgie not long ago and a few days ago it starts showing me that I have installed elementary os !
I missed around abit and done a bit of tweaking and i remember removing ***gir1.2-mutter-2*** as it was written in the terminal that it's not necessary or something like that. I also installed and uninstalled a few desktop environment like cinnamon and gnome (and maybe elementary-desktop i don't quite remember) ... it's not affecting my usage but it's pretty confusing and I wasn't able to install gnome-shell. what should I do ?
should I reinstall it ?

Comment: There are many possible methods of determining the Linux distro that you are running. Which of those many methods are you using?

Comment: Mostly, extra software is installed by the user. So please keep careful notes of what exactly you're doing. For now, I'd go with a complete re-install and then be extremely careful. Many sites recommend trying this desktop and that desktop but then aren't available to help when the user gets stuck or has questions.